# Can't execute the scala^z3 fibonacci example

Tags: scala, z3

I am trying to use Scala^Z3 on MacOS 64 bit, with the following settings:

res0: String = Z3 4.0 (build 0, rev. 0), ScalaZ3 3.2.c (in dev.)

Now when I try to execute the fibonacci example from [the ScalaZ3 main page](http://lara.epfl.ch/w/jniz3-scala-examples), I get the following output, and then the execution halts:

```
fib0 ::: (= (fib!0 0) 0)
fib1 ::: (= (fib!0 1) 1)
fibN ::: (forall (k!0 Int)
  (implies (> k!0 1) (= (fib!0 k!0) (+ (fib!0 (- k!0 1)) (fib!0 (- k!0 2)))))
  :pat {(fib!0 k!0)})
Query ::: (= x (fib!0 1))
```

I waited for some hours, but there is nothing more happening ;)
Does anybody have any ideas, what I am doing wrong? Too new version of scala or z3?
Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 1):

(Note that we haven't had a chance to test Scala^Z3 with the latest version of Z3 yet. Thanks for breaking ground here.)

The problem you're trying to solve contains universal quantifiers and is satisfiable. Past version of Z3 would terminate with `unknown` and you could ask for a tentative model (as shown on the documentation page to which you linked). It could very well be that the newer version is set up to try really hard to disprove the formula rather than return `unknown`, and thus does not terminate.

You can try an unsatisfiable query, which should work better. Try for instance:

```
(= (fib 10) (fib 12))
```

Z3 should be able to instantiate the quantifiers sufficiently many times to conclude that formula is unsatisfiable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Would have expected at least some days, not under 1 hour ;)

The query really was evaluated as unsatisfiable. So I guess I configured the programs right.
Thx for the help! :)